# How to pass Spotify access token retrieved by Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, api, spotify

I am using Spotify web API to get access to user data:

```
public class Application {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    final String clientId = "clientId";
    final String clientSecret = "clientSecret";
    final String redirectURI = "http://localhost:8080/callback/";


    final Api api = Api.builder()
      .clientId(clientId)
      .clientSecret(clientSecret)
      .redirectURI(redirectURI)
      .build();

    /* Set the necessary scopes that the application will need from the user */
    final List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("user-read-private", "user-read-email");

    /* Set a state. This is used to prevent cross site request forgeries. */
    final String state = "someExpectedStateString";

    String authorizeURL = api.createAuthorizeURL(scopes, state);
    /* Here connecting to authorizeURL */   
 }
}
```

Then I connect to authorizeUrl and get the access token (code) from redirectUri which looks like this: *localhost:8080/callback/?code=123*

I can get the code and display it using Spring controller in my localhost:

```
@RestController
public class TokenController {
  private static final String template = "Your Spotify acces code: %s";

  @RequestMapping("/callback/")
  public Token tokenValue(@RequestParam(value="code",  defaultValue="Spotify access code") String value) {
    return new Token(String.format(template, value));
  }
}
```

How do I pass this code back to my Application so that I can finish the process of authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially stored it within the http server and then polled the http server from my application by another API method. Very clunky and potentially insecure.

A later solution was to embed some lightweight http server classes within my application. This allowed me to simply read some class variables. It took quite a lot of integration but the solution is quite clean. It seems a lot of code for one value.

I'm still not happy with this but it will do for now.